# 'Scene' object has no attribute 'rendercycles' error whe saving a Performance preset

Tags: customization, versions

I'm using Blender version 3.3.0 and I was trying to save a Performance preset in the render settings. The problem is that, each time I try to save a new preset with the + button, I receive the following error :

[image: Save a performance preset]

[image: The error]

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\3.3\scripts\startup\bl_operators\presets.py", line 148, in execute
    exec(rna_path)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'rendercycles'
```

And even though the preset is saved, it doesn't do anything when I click on its name on the list, while it's supposed to switch the settings to the ones I set on the preset :

[image: the preset is saved]

I figured I didn't need to upload a blend file because it happens with the startup file.

Is this a bug or is there a way for me to avoid this?

Comment: the API for accessing cycles settings has changed in recent versions, but this shouldn't be happening. You could try downloading the latest 3.4.1 version (where this doesn't happen) or 3.3.1 if you want to stick to 3.3, maybe this has been solved in the corrective release

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I thought so too. I just hoped for another solution.